# brm setting priors with R (Codes)

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian

I am new to the Bayesian approach, and I would like to build a Bayesian mixed-effects linear regression model for my linguistics project. However, I am not really sure about how I should set priors for my model. Below are detailed and simplified descriptions of the model.

Dependent variable: normalized pitch (ranging roughly between -5 and 5)

Fixed effects: Group (3 levels: A, B, C), Type (3 levels: X, Y, Z)

Random effects: (1+Type|Subject) + (Word)

```
>my_priors<-get_prior(Pitch ~ Group*Type+(1+Type|Subject)+(1|Word),
  data = b, family=gaussian)
```

```
> my_priors
                prior     class                coef   group resp dpar nlpar lb ub
               (flat)         b                                                  
               (flat)         b             GroupB                              
               (flat)         b GroupB:TypeY                              
               (flat)         b  GroupB:TypeZ 
               (flat)         b             GroupC                              
               (flat)         b GroupC:TypeY                              
               (flat)         b  GroupC:TypeZ
               (flat)         b         TypeY
               (flat)         b          TypeZ
               lkj(1)       cor                                                  
               lkj(1)       cor                     Subject                      
 student_t(3, 0.9, 3) Intercept                                                  
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd                                              0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd                     Subject                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd           Intercept Subject                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd         TypeY Subject                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd          TypeZ Subject                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd                        Word                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)        sd           Intercept    Word                  0   
   student_t(3, 0, 3)     sigma                                              0   
       source
      default
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
      default
 (vectorized)
      default
      default
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
 (vectorized)
      default
```

The code I would like to use to run the model is as below (please correct me if there is anything incorrect or if you have other suggestions):

```
brm_1 <- brm(
  Pitch ~ Group*Type+(1+Type|Subject)+(1|Word),
  data = b,
  family = gaussian,
  prior = my_priors, ## I need a vector called "my_priors"
  sample_prior = "only", ##I don't understand this one. What does 'only' mean?
  cores = 6,
  threads=threading(4),
   backend = "cmdstanr",
   file = "./Data/"
 )
```

As seen above, I'd like to specify priors by making a vector called "my_priors." I learned that I have to specify the intercept and all beta coefficients based on previous knowledge, but I haven't learned how to do that in R.

I would appreciate it if you could teach me the codes for specifiying priors for this particular model and how I can check the model's validity. Also any other suggestions, tips, advice are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time reading and answering this question.

Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1):

There are different philosophies about priors. The default, flat prior in brms can work in some cases. Many textbooks recommends weakly informative priors. I found this resource extremely useful: https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations. If you want weakly informative priors, see the link above, what I would probably do is use sample_prior = "only", like you do. Then I would probably use the excellent tidybayes package to generate posterior (read prior) draws from the model you fitted with sample_prior = "only".

Something like:

```
library(tidybayes)



group <- c("A", "B", "C")
type <- c("A","B")
prior_data <- crossing(group, type) %>%
  add_epred_draws(YOURMODEL, ndraws = 100) #use your model object
```

I would probably start with this. For this to work, you would need to remove varying intercepts and slopes from your model formula (you can add this later). Once you have done this, you can plot the predictions from the model before seeing the data, like this:

```
ggplot(prior_data, aes(x=factor(group), y=.epred, group=.draw)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

Does the predictions look reasonable? Then you can start to adjust your priors. I hope this helps.